# how to filter groupby object in pandas based on difference of values within the group?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe as listed below:

```
In []: dff = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(8),
                           'B': list('aabbbbcc'),
                           'C':np.random.randint(100,size=8)})
```

which i have grouped based on column `B`

```
  In []: grouped = dff.groupby('B')
```

Now, I want to filter the `dff` based on difference of values in column `'C'`. For example, if the difference between any two points within the group in column `C` is greater than a threshold, remove that row.

If `dff` is:

```
   A  B   C
0  0  a  18
1  1  a  25
2  2  b  56
3  3  b  62
4  4  b  46
5  5  b  56
6  6  c  74
7  7  c   3
```

Then, a threshold of `10` for `C` will produce a final table like:

```
   A  B   C
0  0  a  18
1  1  a  25
2  2  b  56
3  3  b  62
4  4  b  46
5  5  b  56
```

here the grouped category c (small letter) is removed as the difference between the two is greater than 10, but category b has all the rows intact as they are all within 10 of each other.

Comment: but 62 - 46 > 10 so why aren't some of the rows in b discarded?

Comment: but 62 is within 10 of another value in b 56.

Comment: So if you had 3, 4, 23, 24 you'd keep them all?

Comment: yes that would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd do the hard work in numpy:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([2, 3, 14, 15, 54])

In [12]: res = np.abs(a[:, np.newaxis] - a) < 10  # Note: perhaps you want <= 10.

In [13]: np.fill_diagonal(res, False)

In [14]: res.any(0)
Out[14]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

You could wrap this in a function:

```
In [15]: def has_close(a, n=10):
              res = np.abs(a[:, np.newaxis] - a) < n
              np.fill_diagonal(res, False)
              return res.any(0)

In [16]: g = df.groupby('B', as_index=False)

In [17]: g.C.apply(lambda x: x[has_close(x.C.values)])
Out[17]: 
   A  B   C
0  0  a  18
1  1  a  25
2  2  b  56
3  3  b  62
5  5  b  56
```

Comment: hmm... this is pretty interesting..thank you @Andy. Still taking some time to wrap numpy part in my head, but it worked great.